# Why did ctrl-f stop working in LibreOffice?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys, libreoffice

I've basically settled into Unity, but one constant that is kind of giving me agita is that in LibreOffice Calc (and Writer) `ctrl-f` does nothing. I can go to `edit > find ...` and the edit menu even suggests `ctrl-f` as a keyboard shortcut, but actually typing it doesn't do anything. `ctrl-alt-f` works fine. The only thing that doesn't work is `ctrl-f`. I had a really hard time getting settled with Unity (mostly trying to get my old Gnome-do and Compiz settings back) so I spent a lot of time monkeying with the Compiz Settings Manager. But I can't figure out where I would have unset/ overrode this. Plus, it isn't like `ctrl-f` does something unexpected. It just does nothing.

Comment: I also have this same problem, having come from OpenOffice (on Ubuntu and Windows).  This is a '**feature**', that I consider to be an annoying '**bug**'.  Some users clearly agitated for it.  I'll see if there is a simple fix ..

Comment: This is clearly a bug which I reproduced as well. The Edit drop menu clearly indicates <Ctrl>F initiates Find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-map the <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> keyboard action to 'Find & Replace'.

**NOTE:** *The dialog box (Tools >> Customize >> Keyboard) is hard to use, and I was unable to find the existing 'quick find' that is currently mapped to <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd>.*

After several attempts, I was able to map:

- Shortcut keys: <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> - to - Category: '**Edit**', Function: '**Find & Replace**'
- Shortcut keys: <kbd>F3</kbd> - to - Category: '**Edit**', Function: '**Repeat Search**'
- Shortcut keys: <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-F</kbd> - to - ( left blank )

( This clearly needs work, by the LibreOffice maintainers. )

Comment: Ctrl-F does appear to be mapped to "Find" in the keyboard, but as @geoffrey noticed, it pops you to a find box in the toolbar that may or may not be visible

Comment: The issue (_as it affects me_) is that 'Ctrl-F' does **NOT** open the _Find & Replace_ dialog box.  As a long term MS Office/OpenOffice user, that is what I expect when my fingers hit 'Ctrl-F'.  The simple "find next" function is not as helpful ..

Comment: I voted this up, but let me say something in defense of LO. I like two things about the search toolbar: 1) it does not get in the way of text when you search (with the f&r box, sometimes the search term is hidden behind the box, or the box jumps all over the screen), 2) it's easy to search quickly both up and down (with the F&R box, you tick a box to search backwards, and sometimes you forget that box is ticked). I tend to use the simple 'search' function much more than find&replace, so I prefer the unobtrusive toolbar. Only negative in my view is that it takes up so much space on the toolbar.

Comment: Okay, but then don't make ctrl-f go nowhere if the search bar isn't visible.

Comment: +1 - The 'F3' shortcut for "Repeat Search" saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: go to View > Toolbars and check 'Find'. This adds a 'Find' dialog on the toolbar. When you click `ctrl-f` the cursor jumps to that toolbar, then enter the search term, and hit enter, or use the arrows to search up or down.

Comment: I'm kind of incensed that this worked, but it did. Why? Why hide the find dialog?

Comment: I'm realizing that I'm still not happy, so remapping ctrl-f to find and replace. In calc, ctrl-f doesn't switch focus to the find box so I do 'ctrl-f' and type something and I replace content. Not good.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t=273375) I found a simple solution: after deleting $HOME/.libreoffice it worked again. Magic.

Comment: That seems to solve a different problem. `ctrl-f` is mapped to the toolbar find by default now. If you want to re-map it, doing that explicitly seems like a cleaner fix than killing your whole LibreOffice settings directory.

Comment: I agree that deleting the settings is far from convenient. But the search window came back (and I don't see why a user should remap an existing key setting...). The mapping just didn't work, maybe my settings contained the disabling somehow? Anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to have enough karma right now to comment after geoffrey's answer.

However, this could help: first I detached ("undocked") the Find toolbar. This seem to prevent it from materializing docked but out of signt.

Then, I noticed that pressing CTRL+F once make the toolbar appear, but *not* focus it; pressing it a second time *does* focus it.

Granted, this is a bug and should be fixed; but in the meantime, this workaround proved quite useful.

Comment: the solution above does work, buggy as it all is.