# Hotkeys stop working in eclipse

Tags: 11.10, unity, eclipse

I've recently moved to Ubuntu 11.10 (64bit, Unity) and encounter the following problem - at some point (it's hard to tell exactly, but it seems to happen after a couple switches between workspaces, but might as well be something else) hotkeys (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + smth) stop working. I can clearly tell it happens in eclipse, but other apps might have the same problem. After some time they start working normally (after switching windows/workspaces may be).

It's not fatal, but really annoying. Is there some way to fix it?
I've looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81183/why-did-ctrl-f-stop-working-in-libreoffice) question with similar problem, but answers doesn't seem to provide universal solution.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I've figured it out - looks like the problem was caused by having non-english keyboard layout enabled (wonder how I missed that out in the first place).

So solution (for Eclipse) is to go to Window->Preferences->General->Keys and add mappings for other layout that is used (this might look a little bit confusing, since different letters might look the same in different languages (like Russian `В` and English `B`)).

p.s. What's interesting is that Chromium for example doesn't have this problem - might have already enabled mappings for different languages or just handles keys differently.